# upgrading acumatica from 4.10 to latest (6.10)

Tags: acumatica

I'm hesitant to upgrade directly from Acumatica 4.10 to latest (Acumatica 6.10). Is it safe to upgrade it directly to 6.10? or to install and update all patches in between 4.10 and 6.10?

Answer (score 2):

Direct update from 4.10 to 6.x is not supported. You can upgrade in two steps:

Upgrade to 5.3

Upgrade to 6.1

It's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you upgrade through the browser, not in the configuration app, because of the customizations, acumatica system needs to validate the customization if it is safe for the next upgrade path you are taking, adding to Dmitry Naumov's answer, you should be careful for the builds, as it may prevent on upgrading it on the lower build of the next upgrade path.